# Filter (phrase) out specific tags in document

Tags: filtering

I'm on OSX, I was wondering if there is a piece of software out there that allows me to extract specific tags and their value out of a document.

I have an XML that contains path information contained within a tag like this:

```
<pathurl>file://localhost/disk1/pahttofile.mov</pathurl>
```

I need to extract only these tags and the path info.

How would I do this without having to find and copy paste a million times?

THX!
Karel.

Comment: Recommend migration to superuser.SE as finding an external piece of software is off-topic for SO

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614905/xpath-tools-for-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def getpathurls(filename):
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    return [path.text for path in root.findall('pathurl')]
```

Depending on how your file is formatted, this may get you the results you're looking for.

(I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but this is the only way to answer the question on-topic to StackOverflow)